# (Android)I use Path draw a curve on Canvas,how to "select" it?

Tags: android, graphics

I use Path draw a curve on Canvas,I want to select it.
How to determine the point I click is in the curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if your curve is regular,you can calculate it by its mathematical function expression.

If not ,you can paint the curve with a color and then get the color of the point you click to check if they are the same .

Comment: thanks, the second way maybe can do it, i will try .

Answer (score 0):

Region may help you

```
Region region = new Region();
region.setPath(path, null);
region.contains(x, y);
```

Comment: thank you very much. This is the best way! But how to set width?because the curve has a width.

Comment: @kagami you can user path.computeBounds method to retrieve the bounds of path, then pass to setPath method